# On the Importance of the Second and Fourth Isomorphism Theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I suppose I'd like to focus on the theorems for groups and rings, first of all. In particular, I'd rather not see anything about modules, simply because I don't feel I know enough about them.

Anyway, in doing a lot of exercises in group theory and ring theory, I find that I use the first and third isomorphism theorems a lot more than the second and fourth. What I want to see are some really useful-looking applications of the second and fourth theorems that I may not have been exposed to before. Thanks!

EDIT: for clarity, the theorems I identify as the second and fourth are as follows for rings (cf. Dummit & Foote, 3ed p. 246)

The second:
Let $A$ be a subring of $R$ and $B$ be an ideal of $R$. Then $A+B = \{a+b|a \in a, b \in B\}$ is a subring of $R$, $A \cap B$ is an ideal of $A$, and $(A+B)/B \cong A/(A \cap B)$.

The fourth:
Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. The correspondence $A \leftrightarrow A/I$ is an inclusion preserving bijection between the set of subrings $A$ of $R$ that contain $I$ and the set of subrings of $R/I$. Furthermore, $A$ (a subring containing $I$) is an ideal of $R$ if and only if $A/I$ is an ideal of $R/I$.

Comment: It might help to tell us which ones are the 2nd and 4th. I think the naming depends on the source.

Comment: True enough. I'll edit my question now.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308942/applications-of-the-isomorphism-theorems)

Comment: Not entirely. That guy's second is my third. Give me a second to edit my post.

Comment: The use of the 4th Iso Thm. in proving the Sylow Existence Theorem is pretty smooth I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer includes an application of the 4th isomorphism theorem for rings, and one (well, kinda two) of the 2nd isomorphism theorem for groups. I also link to a *really cool* application of the 4th isomorphism theorem in groups (but is kinda the same as the application to rings).

**Rings, 4th isomorphism theorem**

An neat application of the 4th isomorphism theorem for rings is the following:

> **Theorem**: [Maximal ideals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_ideal) are [prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal).

*Proof:* Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be a maximal ideal of $R$. Then consider the quotient $R/I$, and apply the correspondence theorem.

Indeed, if $R$ is commutative with identity then $R/I$ is a field. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/why-are-maximal-ideals-prime/) for a proof.

**Groups, 4th isomorphism theorem**

There is a rather cool trick in the theory of infinite groups, which was used by [Higman](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-26/1/61.extract) to construct an infinite simple group. The idea is to appeal to Zorn's lemma and obtain a maximal normal subgroup, and then quotient this out to get a simple group. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/768729/10513) for a neat application of it. This is very similar to the above application to rings. (You quotient out a maximal subgroup/ideal to get a simple group/prime ring.)

**Groups, 2nd isomorphism theorem**

A nice application of the 2nd isomorphism theorem for groups is the following. It deals with soluble groups, which are an important class of groups (and are often taught in a second course on groups). A group $G$ is *soluble* (or *solvable*) if it possesses an *abelian series*, that is, a series $$1=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\cdots\lhd G_n=G$$ where each factor $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian.

> **Theorem**: Subgroups and homomorphic images of soluble groups are soluble.

*Proof*: Suppose $G$ is soluble with abelian series $1=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\cdots\lhd G_n=G$.

*Subgroups:* If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then we can apply the 2nd isomorphism theorem to get the following.
$$\frac{H\cap G_{i+1}}{H\cap G_i}\cong\frac{(H\cap G_{i+1})G_i}{G_i}\leq\frac{G_{i+1}}{G_i}$$
Hence, the groups $\frac{H\cap G_{i+1}}{H\cap G_i}$ are abelian so the set $\{H\cap G_i; i=0, 1, \ldots, n\}$ forms an abelian series for the group $H$, as required.

*Homomorphic images:* If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then the can apply the 2nd isomorphism theorem to get the following.
$$\frac{G_{i+1}N}{G_iN}\cong\frac{G_{i+1}}{G_{i+1}\cap (G_iN)}$$
The subgroup $G_i$ is a subgroup of $G_{i+1}$ and of $G_iN$, and so $G_i\lhd G_{i+1}\cap (G_iN)$. Therefore, $\frac{G_{i+1}}{G_{i+1}\cap (G_iN)}$ is a homomorphic image of $\frac{G_{i+1}}{G_i}$, and hence is abelian. By the 3rd isomorphism theorem we have the following.
$$\frac{G_{i+1}N/N}{G_iN/N}\cong \frac{G_{i+1}N}{G_iN}$$
Hence, the set $\{G_iN/N; i=0, 1, \ldots, n\}$ forms an abelian series for $G/N$, as required.

Comment: All the answers I've gotten are great, but this one's really something. I appreciate it!

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?...

Answer (score 3):

The fourth isomorphism theorem, as you call it (I call it the correspondence theorem), is used alot in Algebraic Geometry. A good example of how it is used is to show that there is a homeomorphism between the topological spaces
$$\text{Spec}(A)\simeq \text{Spec}(A/\sqrt{0})$$

Where $A$ is a commutative ring and $\sqrt{0}$ is its nilradical. If you are not familiar with $\text{Spec}(A)$, as a set it is the set of prime ideals in $A$. One can then put a topology on this set by declaring the closed sets to be of the form
$$ V(I) = \{p\in\text{Spec}(A) : I\subset p\}.$$

Here $I$ is an ideal in $A$.

The correspondence theorem allows us to check that $\text{Spec}(A)$ and $\text{Spec}(A/\sqrt{0})$ are in bijective correspondence with each other. Indeed, it says that prime ideals in $A$ are in bijection with prime ideals in $A/\sqrt{0}$ that contain $\sqrt{0}$. However, every prime ideal contains $\sqrt{0}$ thus giving the bijection.

It then required more work to show that two topological spaces are homeomorphic, but as far I can recall, that does not require the correspondence theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Notice as a special case $(M+N)/N=M$ if the sum is direct (meaning $M\cap N=0$). This is frequently used. For instance if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, and $FX$ is the free group on $X$ we have $F(X\coprod Y)=FX\oplus FY$, so that $F(X\coprod Y)/FY=FX$ is free, this is sometimes useful in algebraic topology.

As for the fourth: let me assure you that if you study a bit of commutative algebra and algebraic geometry you use this ALL THE TIME, its basically useful to figure out the ideals of quotient rings, which come up there.